# ASP.net viewbag displaying 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem I have no idea how to solve.
I am getting 0 for all my Options in my dropdown.
I am trying to display data in a viewbag in a dropdown list

[image: What i get]

[image: id and vlannumber removed]

it becomes like this if i remove id and vlannumber from controller

```
ViewData["Customervlancode"] = new SelectList(VLANDDisnull, "Id","VlanNumber");
```

im trying to get it to display like all the other FKs in my view..
this is my code.

Controller

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {

            
            List<object> CvlanDB = new List<object>(_db.CustomerVlans);

            CvlanDB.Count();

            var VLANDDisnull = from myobject in _db.CustomerVlans
                          where myobject.DisconnectionDate == null
                          select myobject;
            

            ViewData["Customercode"] = new SelectList(_db.Customers, "Id", "CompanyName");
            ViewData["Customervlancode"] = new SelectList(VLANDDisnull);
            ViewData["Switchcode"] = new SelectList(_db.Switchzs, "Id", "SwitchName");


            return View();
        }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Customervlancode" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Customervlancode" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Customervlancode"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Customercode" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Customercode" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Customercode"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Switchcode" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Switchcode" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Switchcode"></select>
        </div>
```

How can I display the VlanNumber values